# Combining lists of dictionaries based on list index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I feel like this question must have been asked previously but could not find it on Stack Overflow.

Is there a way to elegantly combine multiple lists of dictionaries based on list index? See below:

```
list_1 = [{'hello': 'world'}, {'foo': 'test'}]
list_2 = [{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}]
result = [{'hello': 'world', 'a': 'b'},
          {'foo': 'test', 'c': 'd'}]
```

I understand that I can technically use a for loop such as:

```
list_3 = []
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    list_3.append({**list_1[i],**list_2[i]})
```

Is there a way to do this with list comprehension?
Also what if I have more than 2 lists involved or do not know the number of lists of dictionaries?

Comment: "I understand that I can technically use a for loop such as for i in range(0,len(list_1) but is there a way to do this with list comprehension?" What is the motivation of this question? There's no guarantee that a list comp will be any faster and you haven't shown any effort in the `for` loop approach.

Comment: Fair enough, I have my example above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
result = [{**x, **y} for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]

# [{'a': 'b', 'hello': 'world'}, {'c': 'd', 'foo': 'test'}]
```

See [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448) for an explanation of `**` syntax.

For a generalised solution:

```
list_1=[{'hello':'world'},{'foo':'test'}]
list_2=[{'a':'b'},{'c':'d'}]
list_3=[{'e':'f'},{'g':'h'}]

lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in dict_args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

result = [merge_dicts(*i) for i in zip(*lists)]

# [{'a': 'b', 'e': 'f', 'hello': 'world'}, {'c': 'd', 'foo': 'test', 'g': 'h'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a generalizable solution, in Python 3, you could do something like:

```
In [14]: from operator import or_

In [15]: from functools import reduce

In [16]: list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2]

In [17]: [dict(reduce(or_, map(dict.items, ds))) for ds in zip(*list_of_lists)]
Out[17]: [{'a': 'b', 'hello': 'world'}, {'c': 'd', 'foo': 'test'}]
```

In Python 2, no need to import `reduce`, since it is already in the global namespace, but you will need to use `dict.viewitems` instead of `dict.items`:

```
[dict(reduce(or_, map(dict.viewitems, ds))) for ds in zip(*list_of_lists)]
```

Note the only real problem with your solution that I can see is that it uses `for i in range(...)`, when you should just loop over the `zip`pped lists.

Comment: From the `for` loop in the question: `1.02 µs ± 2.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`. This answer: `3.32 µs ± 55.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`. However, the list comp in the other answer does speed it up a bit: `933 ns ± 15.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`. This is is in 3.6 btw.

Comment: Yes, the fasted way to get a merge of the `dict`s is to use a forloop with `update`. using the `reduce(or_, map(dict.viewkeys))` will be slower since there is an intermediate step of creating a view, then converting the view into a dict.

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter prematurely. I posted the stats in relation to my initial comment; list comps aren't necessarily faster.

Comment: @roganjosh an alternative, that maintains generality but is more performant (although with substantial overhead so if the `dict` objects are small, it might not be worth it): `dict(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, ds)))`

Comment: That's a fair point, my timings are with very small samples. I'm probably not awake enough to build a full test case for bigger samples; if the OP is concerned with speed then the question should have contained a more-reasonable test case IMO.